# Номинация правки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Если сделать правку сообщения, а потом быстро откатить назад (в течение 5 минут), то [в истории возникает следующее сообщение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3279/2):

> [Правка удалена в течение номинации ]

По-моему, с этим сообщением что-то не так, и проблема не только в лишнем пробеле.

Comment: в английском сообщении используется термин grace period, он переводится на русский калькой - грейс-период. Но проблема в том, что в русскоговорящих странах кредитование не слишком распространено, и термин практически неузнаваем для обычных программистов :(

Comment: Сделал [правку](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3279/2), иллюстрирующую использование строки.

Comment: Почему это сообщение вообще попадает в историю ревизий? Какая от него польза сообществу?

Comment: @alexolut хотя на сам вопрос либо ответ такая "нулевая" правка не влияет - она влияет на его мета-информацию (например, на дату последнего изменения). Без подобных правок в истории можно, к примеру, скрытно "апать" вопросы в списке последних измененных.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3295/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-grace-period-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83/3299#3299

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы сразу было понятно, как это работает и каков период.

> Правка была отменена в течение пяти минут

Comment: Если период иной, соответственно ставим "трёх", "семи", "четырёх с четвертью" или что там ещё.

Comment: А если это время изменится - переводить по-новой? Или сформировать строку динамически с учетом интервала?

Comment: @alexolut C момента реализации фичи на заре SO это время не менялось ни разу.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info

Comment: Без пояснения кажется, что это может сделать кто угодно - лишь бы 5 минут не прошло. Но это не так. Это даже для автора не так, если кто-то успеет оставить комментарий. Так что такая формулировка вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: @Qwertiy Альтернативный путь - утвердить перевод для `grace-period` и сделать подробное толкование в [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/330339) и/или [тегах](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info), чтобы потом опираться на него как на технический термин. Пока русскоязычного термина нет, приходится либо перегружать текст пояснениями, либо изобретать новые слова, либо закрывать глаза на часть подробностей. Предлагаю сейчас закрыть глаза, чтобы улучшить перевод. Затем можем утвердить термин для грейс-периода и ещё раз улучшить перевод.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, а чем не устраивают варианты, в которых не используется время? Например, написано "быстро", или мой вариант про неверсионируемое редактирование (кстати, в нём же можно даже ссылку на подробное описание поставить)?

Comment: @Qwertiy Меня вполне устраивает вариант, который мы комментируем.  Я воспринял ваш комментарий как упрёк в неполноте формулировки и, в общем-то, с ним согласился. Но предлагаю уточнять формулировку после того, как определится перевод для грейс-периода и появится объяснение, что это за зверь.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, а мне кажется, здесь есть варианты лучше. Например: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3283/178988 http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3282/178988 http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3280/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy в оригинале не уточняется, что правку отменил именно автор. Не вижу смысла нам это уточнять.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в моей версии тоже не уточняется :) Просто когда есть какой-то термин, он наталкивает на мысль, что не всё так просто. А когда говорят про 5 минут, то всё кажется очевидным. А на самом деле всё не так. Не следует добавлять во фразу лишнюю информацию, которая способствует неточной интерпретации. 5 минут - зачем? Просто "быстро" - и уже есть повод поискать, а что же это такое.

Comment: @Qwertiy 5 минут - точная информация. Но неполная, поскольку грейс период [может закончиться раньше](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/330339). А "быстро" - слишком уж  невнятное слово. Это 5 секунд , 5 часов или 5 дней? Лучше уж сразу пояснить, насколько быстро. И подробности проще искать для "[пяти минут](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=5+minutes)", чем для "быстро".

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, можно ничего не искать, если сделать слово "быстро" ссылкой :)

Comment: @Qwertiy зачем прятать информацию за ссылкой, если её можно дать сразу? По умолчанию это пять минут. Что чужая правка сразу сохранит эту - практически очевидно. О нечастой ситуации с комментарием можно рассказать в справке.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если давать ссылку на подробное описание, то какое-то слово или фразу следует выбрать для ссылки. Делать ссылку из сочетания "5 минут" мне кажется весьма странным.

Comment: @Qwertiy Создал вопрос "[Перевод термина `grace-period` и пояснений к нему](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3295/)".

Comment: Использовал вариант «свежая правка отменена» [из ответа](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3299/6) в соседнем вопросе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ок.

Answer (score 2):

А надо ли переводить дословно?

> Правка быстро отменена

Comment: "Была" не добавить?

Comment: @Qwertiy "Правка быстро отменена была, юный падаван"

Comment: @alexolut тогда уж "отменена быстро была правка"

Answer (score 2):

> Тут была правка, но ее автор передумал и быстро отменил ее

Answer (score -1):

[Повторюсь:](/a/3238/178988)

> (Правка отменена во время периода неверсионируемого редактирования)

Comment: Думаю, в конце концов перевод станет похожим на этот. Но я за менее пугающий термин для грейс-периода. Хочется понятного и приветливого русского слова.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, сайт программистов, о системах контроля версий знают почти все, так что мне кажется, что термин будет достаточно понятен. С другой стороны, я не против на что-то его заменить, но более хороших идей в голову не пришло. Если есть варианты, то буду рад их услышать.

Comment: Ну я сразу проголосовал за этот вариант, если что.

Comment: [Общие рекомендации по переводу](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1136/208926): `Работая над переводом, мы стараемся использовать как можно более литературный язык, по возможности избегать заимствованных слов. По нашему мнению, такой перевод позволяет быстрее разобраться в сложном функционале сайта и предоставляет лучший опыт пользователю.`

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, я только за. Но у меня подходящих вариантов нет.

Answer (score -2):

[Microsoft называет это "периодом отсрочки"](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=3&s=grace%20period&sc=847&l1=1&l2=2). Соответственно:

> Правка отменена в период отсрочки сохранения [правки]

Answer (score -3):

Краткое уведомление о событии:

> Правка отменена.

Comment: Путается с откатом правки.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо. Теперь понятна причина.

Answer (score -3):

.....

> [Тут могла быть правка]

Answer (score -3):

Захотелось чего-то основе [фразы](//meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info)

> The grace period, or "the ninja edit zone,"

и получилось такое:

> Автор как ниндзя затёр свою правку - быстро и незаметно

Comment: Видишь правку? Нет. А она есть!