# Статья, объясняющая термин «grace period» для редактирования сообщений

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, термины

Мы перевели термин «grace period» как «[свежую правку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3295/)» и с её помощью перевели [сообщение об удалении правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3279/),

Но в дополнение к термину нужна статья, которая объяснит новичкам, зачем этот термин нужен и как он работает на сайте. Тексты на английском:

- [описание тега `grace-period`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info)
- [FAQ How do edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/330339)
- [пояснение к фразе `Edit removed during grace period`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262894/6263942)
- [в каких случаях грейс-период закончится раньше, чем через 5 минут](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288559/6263942)

Каким должен быть текст?
Где его опубликовать?
Как организовать работу над текстом?

Comment: Думаю, можно добавить два-три абзаца сюда: [Почему кто-то может редактировать мои сообщения? Как работает система редактирования?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)