# Как моя правка могла удалить часть вопроса если я его не удалял?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, правки

Предложил только что [правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/295420). Вроде все должно было быть нормально, но потом зашел в статус правки и вижу что ее отклоняют. Смотрю на предпросмотр, и там по непонятной мне причине появился какой-то код который я вроде как удалил. Хотя я четко помню что там кода никакого не было, я просто исправил заголовок и отредактировал ошибки в словах. Кода там ВООБЩЕ не было. Теперь в статусе правки стоит что я предложил разрушающую вопрос проверку. Я как-бы это понимаю, но код я не трогал, его там вообще не было. Не могу понять в чем прикол.

Comment: Автор редактировал свой вопрос, вы тоже. Но дело в том, что первые пять минут после создания вопроса ("грейс период") правки автором своего ответа не попадают в историю. (Аналогично и с правками спустя долгое время: две правки с интервалом менее чем пять минут схлопнутся в одну). Поэтому КМК вы начав предлагать редакцию столкнусь с правками автора.

Comment: я вас понял, то есть нужно ждать желательно минут 5 и тогда можно редактировать вопрос?

Comment: Я хорошо знаю, [как работает грейс](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3314/213987), но меня смущает в моём предположении то, что вы не видели сообщения "ответ был изменён перед вашим комментарием". Поэтому я и писал "как мне кажется" и до конца не уверен, что было именно так, как я предположил. В любом случае если вы читаете вопрос, видите что он свежий и на сообщении постоянно появляется плашка "вопрос был изменён" - то лучше не править прям сразу.